# MySQL Unique Item Count Query

Tags: mysql

I have this table on mysql.

```
CustomerName CustomerGroup hasPurchase
Jerry        A             CAR
Jerry        A             TOY
Jerry        A             CAR
Springer     B             DRINK
Springer     B             CAR
Springer     B             CAR
Springer     B             DRINK
```

My Expected Result:

```
CustomerName CustomerGroup totalPurchase    uniquePurchase
Jerry        A             3                2
Springer     B             4                2
```

`totalPurchase` is the total items he bought.
`uniquePurchase` is the different type of item he purchased.

what is the correct mysql query for this? Thx for the help.

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: Show your tried code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerName,
                CustomerGroup,
                COUNT(hasPurchase) as totalPurchase,
                COUNT(DISTINCT hasPurchase) as uniquePurchase
FROM XXX
GROUP BY CustomerName,
         CustomerGroup
```

I don't have run it on MySQL, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming customerName and customerGroup are same for each row, use `count` and `count` with `distinct` along with `group by`

```
select customerName
,customerGroup
,count(hasPurchase) as totalPurchase
,count(distinct hasPurchase) as uniquePurchase
from your_table
group by CustomerName,CustomerGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try group by  for this

`Count(hasPurchase)` for taotalPurchase

`Count(Distinct hasPurchase)` for uniquePurchase

```
SELECT customerName,customerGroup,count(hasPurchase) as totalPurchase,count(distinct hasPurchase) as uniquePurchase
from table group by CustomerName;
```